# Change ActionbarTitle using ViewPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

Currently i am trying to deveolop an app which implements swiping between different views.
The swiping works fine, but i want to set the title of the view to the actionbar, that the users knows where he is.

So i hope you can give me some ideas where i had to put the code for the title change.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set up an [`OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) for your `ViewPager`. When you swipe, the `OnPageChangeListener` will be notified, and you can change the `ActionBar` title from the callback.

Here's some pseudo code for you:

```
ViewPager vp;
vp.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        getActionBar().setTitle(titles[position]); // Set the correct title based on the position
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {} // not used

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {} // not used
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setTitle (CharSequence title)

Change the title associated with this activity. If this is a top-level activity, the title for its window will change. If it is an embedded activity, the parent can do whatever it wants with it.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle(int)

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int pos) {
                    // Chage the title
                }


                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Comment: i know how to change the title in the actionbar. the problem is if I swipe to the next view the title should change, but this doesnt work.
So i need the place where i had to put the code for changing the title properly